# How to deal with hostile ships, stations and lasertowers after mending relationships with a faction?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

After improving my standing with a faction that wasn't previously very hot about me, I keep finding lingering hostile ships, stations and lasertowers. Not only does this hippie sensibilities, but they also often attack my remote ships or deny the trade of valuable resources. How can I convince them to forgive and forget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lingering hostile ships can often be dealt with by apologizing and/or scanning (make sure you have a valid police license to scan in that sector).  If that fails, make them have an 'accident' with a bigger ship.

Stations have to be hacked by hiring a hacker, who show up as a lightbulb icon (note that the icon may be overridden by another mission type, so make sure to open comms with every station with a mission icon if you are desperate). They can be found on any pirate installation as well as race-controller stations in border systems within 3 jumps of a hostile station, as stations further away cannot be hacked.

Lasertowers are the most annoying.  The only way I have found is to destroy them. You can avoid reputation loss by destroying them in as few hits as possible, though you will lose your police license; the best way is to shoot a Hammerhead missile at it, since it will destroy the lasertower in 1 shot. Often, this will cause an attached station to become hostile, so you'll have to rehack them, although contacting the station and requesting docking permission *may* turn it blue.

Comment: Where might I find station hackers? How can I minimize reputation loss when destroying lasertowers?

Comment: @kotekzot station hackers can appear as light bulbs at stations.  They can only hack hostile stations within 3 sectors of finding one, so just talk to every lightbulb person you see as you fly around.  As for minimzing lasertowers, there used to be a way to destroy one without taking a rep penalty but I'm not sure if its possible anymore (you place a cheap station like a wheat factory on top of it to cause collisions until it dies :P)

Comment: I've added some of my own observations to your answer, feel free to delete them if you feel they change your answer too much or are wrong. P.S.: I think the station hack range is actually 5 jumps, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Nope, the range does seem to be 3 sectors.